# Create secret only if not exists or else use the existing one

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to create a secret which needs to get created only if it is not existing, or else assign the existing ones when i do `helm upgrade` . I tried the below code

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: "{{.Release.Namespace}}-mongodb-secret"
type: Opaque
data:  
  {{- $secretObj := (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace "{{.Release.Namespace}}-mongodb-secret") | default dict }}
  {{- $secretData := (get $secretObj "data") | default dict }}    
  {{- $mongodbpasswords := (get $secretData "mongodb-passwords") | default (randAlphaNum 8 | b64enc) }}
  mongodb-passwords: {{ $mongodbpasswords | quote }}
  {{- $mongodbrootpassword := (get $secretData "mongodb-root-password") | default (randAlphaNum 8 | b64enc) }}
  mongodb-root-password: {{ $mongodbrootpassword | quote }}
```

First time it works well, i.e it creates these pwds.When i do `helm upgrade` i am expecting it not to create a new set of pwds, i.e do not change the password, but it is creating again. What am i missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$secretObj` assignment has an embedded Helm command.  Try this instead:

```
{{- $secretObj := (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace (printf "%s-mongodb-secret" .Release.Namespace)) | default dict }}
```